# Mongoose JS findOne returning NULL

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My code below is returning NULL immediately when it should return a document, seems to be specific to this collection as my other findOne's for different collections are working as expected.

```
function findData(rowObj) {
  console.log(rowObj.field);
  console.log(Mongoose.connection.readyState);
  return DataImport.findOne({
    ROW: rowObj.field
  });
}
```

My collection has many fields, ideally I wouldn't use a schema as I am not updating or adding from this collection, just reading from it;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const dataImportSchema = new Schema({});

const DataImport = mongoose.model(
  'DataImport',
  dataImportSchema,
  'DataImport'
);

module.exports = DataImport;
```

I have however tried this with all of the document fields in the schema but get the same result.

Is it possible an issue with the collection being too large? It is 30GB with around 40 million documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have been using an old way of specifying the collection name and should have had it in the schema definition: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

`